# Javascript on pdf to find the most selected value

Tags: javascript, mode

I have an employee appraisal form. There are 9 objectives and each objective has 5-16 sub-objectives where the 'rater' will rate the employee for that task as Not Applicable, Not Met, Met, or Exceeded.

I am looking for a javascript to look at the list of items within each objective and display the most selected option. The dropdown fields are named Objective 1 Rating. The field to display the answer is Score 1.

For example, Objective 1 has 6 sub-objectives.
1 Not Applicable
1 Not Met
3 Met
1 Exceeded

"Score 1" should display "Met".

Also, in the event that there is a tie between 2 answers I'll need some logic on that. I have tried doing if else if statements and switch statements but it doesn't work properly.

I have tried if else if statements. I assigned each option a number:
0 has a value of Not Applicable
1 has a value of Not Met
100 has a value of Met
200 has a value of Exceeded

It worked when Not Applicable was 0 however the client wants Not Applicable to have weight.

I also tried a switch statement but kept running into syntax errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Bli.png)

Comment: It impossible to help without a code. Please give us some code. Also, it's not clear how is out relevant to PDFs.

Comment: Its a pdf form. Within the form I have text field that holds the code.


Something like this, but its saying I have a syntax error missing ; before statement 2 at line 3.

function findhighestOccurenceAndNum(Objective1Rating) {
  let obj = {};
  let maxNum, maxVal;
  for (let v of a) {
    obj[v] = ++obj[v] || 1;
    if (maxVal === undefined || obj[v] > maxVal) {
      maxNum = v;
      maxVal = obj[v];
    }
  }
  console.log(maxNum + ' has max value = ' + maxVal);
}

findhighestOccurenceAndNum(['Not Applicable', 'Not Met', 'Met', 'Exceeded']);

Comment: I also found this script but I don't know where to enter my field names.

function modeString(array) {
  if (array.length == 0) return null;

  var modeMap = {},
    maxEl = array[0],
    maxCount = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var el = array[i];

    if (modeMap[el] == null) modeMap[el] = 1;
    else modeMap[el]++;

    if (modeMap[el] > maxCount) {
      maxEl = el;
      maxCount = modeMap[el];
    } else if (modeMap[el] == maxCount) {
      maxEl += "&" + el;
      maxCount = modeMap[el];
    }
  }
  return maxEl;